# GetX (state management) STOP updating

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, state-management, flutter-state

I notice that [GetX package](https://pub.dev/packages/get) hasn't update for 13 months, more than 1 year & still stand at version 4.6.5. Compare to other state management packages, it's very long days. [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx) has latest update 4 months ago. **Is the era of GetX coming to the end**?

GetX has many dramas & many people doesn't like it (checkout [this article](https://medium.com/@m-zimmermann1/why-you-will-regret-using-getx-for-flutter-2023-4bd7b710fa47)). But in the other hand, so much projects have been using this package & my company's project is one of those. I'm afraid that when GetX dies, our project would dies too (so that we're transferring to BloC). Do anyone knows what're happening to GetX & **is the era of GetX coming to the end**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`jonataslaw/getx` issues 2834](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/2834) ("Is there any updates of GetX ?") remains the latest official status:

[Alok Dubey](https://github.com/alok2811) asks:

> One year of no updates and no communication from the developer @jasonlaw can you Please update it ASAP or let me know when you will go for release 5.0.0?

[Jonny Borges](https://github.com/jonataslaw), creator of GetX, reports (June 2023):

> I am coding the new update right now.

So a 5.0.0 is in the work.

---

Aug. 2023, [Jonny Borges (`jonataslaw`)](https://github.com/jonataslaw) himself adds:

> To be honest, an update was almost ready, so the new version of Flutter broke the new update.
> But today I fixed some problems, and I'm optimistic. We'll have a version 5 soon (once I fix `RouterOutlet`).

The [4.6.6](https://pub.dev/packages/get/versions/4.6.6) release(Sept. 8th) is there, even though it is not listed in the [jonataslaw/getx repository](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/releases).

Comment: Still worry buddy, last commit is 4 months ago & number of issues is 778 - what a huge amount!

Comment: @Nguyenfamily I understand. I simply echo the latest (July first, 2023, 4 days ago) from the creator of the project himself.

Answer (score 2):

Getx is obviously not going to die. I am not any kind of expert but I have been in contact with many experts and have attended flutter developer meet also. Getx has already released the prerelease version of Getx with version 5.0.0.
Soon stable release will be there.

Answer (score 0):

An update from the [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) site:

GetX has updated their stable release to - [get: ^4.6.6](https://pub.dev/packages/get/versions/4.6.6) (3 days ago)

GetX has updated their prerelease release to - [get: ^5.0.0-release-candidate-5](https://pub.dev/packages/get/versions/5.0.0-release-candidate-5) (2 days ago)

It means the maintainer is working on it & they didn't ditch it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's not going to die. And it's the best one there. 4 days ago they released a new one.
And best Getx tutorial [enter link description here](https://youtu.be/7dAt-JMSCVQ)

Comment: I think you meant https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfOdpqJc62w

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).